# Zinc and brewer's yeast

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, nutrition

I'm hoping for some information relating to yeast nutrition (specifically *Saccharomyces cerevisea*) in beer fermentation.

Zinc is [well-known](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter6-9-1.html) to be necessary for yeast cultures to perform successful fermentations and since fermentable sugars derived from barley are often deficient in zinc, they are sometimes fortified with additions of zinc sulfate or zinc chloride. [This guy](http://braukaiser.com/blog/blog/2012/06/22/the-effect-of-zinc-on-fermentation-performance/) tried zinc gluconate, a readily available dietary supplement for the same purpose, and found it to have very little, if any, positive effect on fermentation performance. As he even suggests at the end of his paper, could this be because yeast can't assimilate Zn from this molecule the same way it does from the other two?

Is this question better directed towards [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)?

Thanks in advance for any help I can get on this.

Comment: You can ask this question in homebrew.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I actually came here *from* the HBSE to ask this question.